# Derby how to change port number (also for stop script)

Tags: derby, port-number

I noticed that if I set another port number instead of the default one in derby (1527) in the derby.properties with for instance:

```
derby.drda.portNumber=1528
```

It will then correctly start up the server on that new port but unfortunately when calling stop script it will still attempt to kill something on the default port and leaving the derby alive. Is that a bug or is there something else that needs to be addressed in the properties file to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `-p portnumber` argument to `stopNetworkServer`: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/adminguide/tadminconfigshuttingdownthenetworkserver.html

Comment: Well not really because I was hoping to to use the derby.property instead of having to add -p  options to start and stop scripts. Now what is curious about this is that the property setting works for the start script but not for the stop. So I really start think it might be a bug..